# Previously working domain name, suddenly 'no records found'

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

The domain name is question: cleangreenpgh.com.

I host a few web client websites on my co-located Mac server. Domains are through OpenSRS. Four domains in all, using same records to point to respective websites on co-lo'ed Mac, all working over the past several months without issue until I received an email about the above mentioned website not resolving.

Sites such as mxtoolbox, any dns or 'a' record searches all come up as 'no records found' though the settings in my OpenSRS panel are correct - that is to say the other three domains / websites are resolving normally.

NS for cleangreenpgh.com are set to dns(1,2,3).systemdns.com. A records created to point cleangreenpgh.com to 199.38.85.52.

**=============== UPDATE / ADDITIONAL INFO =================**
Thank you for the replies.

The domain was renewed on Feb 8, I did the renewal myself and have all of the records. In fact, my openSRS panel shows this info...

```
170028710   cleangreenpgh.com   Renewal 1   completed   2014/Feb/07 11:02:16 PM
```

I'd post a screenshot, but I don't have the reputation for such.

As for receiving negative post ratings - I realize that 98% of these types of questions are due to a lack of even the most trivial of networking knowledge. But why give a negitive rating way before the question is even concluded? Is there an "authority" on positive / negative ratings? Someone who has a final say... or can anyone who looks at the post just assume I am an idiot and give a negative rating before getting through to the end of line two? I have followed the guidelines offered on the "How to Ask" page. It's a deterrent to read the post.

Comment: when you renew it don't forget to make sure your contact email is up to date.  Most registrars send you several reminder emails before a domain expires.

Comment: And for next time the command you need to figure this out is 'whois mydomain.com'

Comment: Info updated above - I renewed with all email addresses in proper place etc. (please see above) thanks for the replies.

Comment: I registered my domain for 1 year, 2 weeks ago. I set an A record yesterday and it was all working. Suddenly, for no reason, no DNS records from multiple sources. Friends and family confirmed same from their locations and devices. I checked DNS records, they were perfect and exactly as I set them the day before. I still have no idea what the issue is...

Answer (score 8):

Looks like your domain registration has expired -- cleangreenpgh.com is on Client Hold status. The expiry date is showing as 2015 because they temporarily add a year to an expired domain to give you a chance to renew before it becomes generally available. See the relevant help page [here](http://www.tucowsdomains.com/whois-use-and-information/why-is-my-domain-on-%E2%80%9Cclient-hold%E2%80%9D-or-registrar-hold-in-the-whois-lookup/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I did in fact renew it myself (I added an update to my original post above) and I see the reflecting data in my OpenSRS control panel.

Comment: @IAmEric In that case, OpenSRS has placed the domain on hold for some other reason. You should contact them to find out why.